# The calling thread can not access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with thread, I want to display a text on my txtoutput(textbox) when I receive a SMS I have done that but doesn't work.

```
private void Output(string text)
{
    this.expander.IsExpanded = true; // Exception catched: The calling thread can not access this object because a different thread owns it.

    if (txtOutput.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        txtOutput.AppendText(text);
        txtOutput.AppendText("\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        this.txtOutput.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate
         {
             //  txtOutput.AppendText += text Environment.NewLine;
             txtOutput.AppendText(text);
             txtOutput.AppendText("\r\n");
         }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this instead

```
private void Output(string text)
{
    if (txtOutput.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        this.expander.IsExpanded = true;
        txtOutput.AppendText(text);
        txtOutput.AppendText("\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        this.txtOutput.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate
         {
             this.expander.IsExpanded = true;
             //  txtOutput.AppendText += text Environment.NewLine;
             txtOutput.AppendText(text);
             txtOutput.AppendText("\r\n");
         }); 
    }
}
```

Improved version:

```
private void Output(string text)
{
    if (!txtOutput.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
         this.txtOutput.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate
         {
             Output(text); //Call this function again on the correct thread!
         });
         return;
    }
    this.expander.IsExpanded = true;
    txtOutput.AppendText(text);
    txtOutput.AppendText("\r\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks; it worked but my mind doesn't, why am I setting the expander in a wrong way ?

Comment: i have no idea what a expander is, but my guess is that its some sort of control? and you try to modify the control on the wrong thread, you get a exception thats why you have to use the Dispatcher.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the text of `txtOutput` in a correct way (`CheckAccess()` and `BeginInvoke`). Do the same with `expander`.